# create two variables from user input in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Hi I am new to ruby and I am trying to create a first a last name variables from a single user input line and then concatenate their full name back to them. This is what I have but I don't know if I am doing it correctly.

```
  def first
    @first
  end

  def last
    @last
  end

print "Enter your first and last name: "


first = gets.chomp
last = gets.chomp


print "Hello, " + @first + @last + "!"

end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you're not doing it correctly. Ditch the methods. And the instance variables. Use local variables.

```
print "Enter your first and last name: "


first = gets.chomp
last = gets.chomp


print "Hello, " + first + last + "!"
```

Comment: Thank you! I'll be sure to give you the question answered when I can! :)

Comment: @RyanGlass it's more common to use string interpolation, i.e. `"Hello, #{first} #{last}!"` instead of `+`. And you probably want `puts` instead of `print` to add a newline.

Comment: Ryan, further to @Stefan's comment, you could skip the variables and write `"Hello, #{gets.chomp} #{gets.chomp}!"` or `"Hello, %s %s!" % [gets.chomp}, gets.chomp]`. Also, [String#strip](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/String.html#method-i-strip) would be better than [String#chomp](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/String.html#method-i-chomp) because `strip` removes all leading and trailing whitespace whereas `chomp` only removes the newline: `"  cat  \n".chomp #=> "  cat  " ; "  cat  \n".strip #=> "cat"`...

Comment: ... In real life you probably would be doing some checks on the user input rather than using it blindly. For example, what if the user entered an empty string for `first` and, say, `"Cher"` for `last`?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out another way of getting the two variables from a single user input thank you for all your guys' help. This was the end code.

```
print "Enter your first and last name: "

first, last = gets.chomp.split

print "Hello, " + first + " " + last + "!"
```